Issues with Using `--extra-index-url` in `uv` with Google Cloud Artifact Registry
I'm trying to create a uv project that uses an --extra-index-url with Google Cloud Artifact Registry. According to the uv documentation, this should be possible. I am using uv 0.4.18.  Here's what I've tried so far:
gcloud auth application-default login --project ${PROJECT_ID}                      
uv venv
source .venv/bin/activate
uv pip install keyring keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
uv pip install --keyring-provider subprocess ${MY_PACKAGE} --extra-index-url https://${REGION}-python.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY_ID}/simple                            

However, it returns an error indicating that my package can't be found. Interestingly, when I use standard Python, I can install my private package without any issues. Here's the code that works:
gcloud auth application-default login --project ${PROJECT_ID}                      
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install keyring keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
pip install ${MY_PACKAGE} --extra-index-url https://${REGION}-python.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY_ID}/simple                            

It seems like others have faced this issue before, as mentioned in this closed GitHub issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem or found a workaround? Any help would be appreciated!

Looking at the documentation, it suggests setting UV_KEYRING_PROVIDER and UV_EXTRA_INDEX_URL instead, maybe try that first?

I have tried it and did not work. Anyway, this should not be important since these environment variables should have the same effect as the parameters --extra-index-url and --keyring-provider.

Pointing to the solution of the issue here:
The code that works is:
gcloud auth application-default login --project ${PROJECT_ID}                      
uv venv
source .venv/bin/activate
uv pip install keyring keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
uv pip install ${MY_PACKAGE} --keyring-provider subprocess --extra-index-url https://oauth2accesstoken@${REGION}-python.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY_ID}/simple


The addition of the oauth2accesstoken string in the URL is necessary for the keyring CLI to retrieve a password, as pointed out in uv's GitHub issue 1520.

As stated here at this github

The only thing that knowingly doesn't work is if you have a package that exists both in your private registry and on PyPI (i.e., packages with the same name), and you expect to use a version of that package from PyPI instead of your private registry.

You may also check this  github

would be good to mention in release notes that anyone using keyring subprocess with Google Artifact Registry should update index-urls with oauth2accesstoken@

Clarify docs example for keyring subprocess auth with Google Artifact Registry

the docs here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/authentication/ on auth is missing some vital info for auth with Google Artifact Registry.
Trying to use the new keyring delegation calling with
Does not work
--index-url=https://us-east4-python.pkg.dev/<project>/<repo>/simple <package_name>

Does work
--index-url=https://oauth2accesstoken@us-east4-python.pkg.dev/<project>/<repo>/simple
<package_name>


You may also check the suggestions link1, link2 & link3. If the suggested workaround does not help, try running  the pip install command with the -v (verbose) flag to get more detailed output, which might give insights into why the package isn’t found,  you can try opening a new issue and track the progress there.

Thanks, for replying, I do not think it is an issue of an existing name in Pypi. I have written a message on the closed issue.

Unfortunately, the links and the verbose flag did not help much :(

I have updated my answer as per the open issue here please check,  same suggested by ffissore

Thanks! It worked with the command bellow:
uv pip install ${MY_PACKAGE} --keyring-provider subprocess --extra-index-url https://oauth2accesstoken@${REGION}-python.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${REPOSITORY_ID}/simple
